# One to many queries in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is my City object:

```
class City(Base):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
```

And this is my user:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Base):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100, null=True, unique=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

How do I query cities which have more than 1 user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use annotations:

```
from django.db.models import Count
City.objects.annotate(user_count=Count("user")).filter(user_count__gt=1)
```

Comment: Does this return the count of cities with more than one user?

Comment: No, it returns the cities, not the count.

Comment: This gives me a syntax error, is this complete code?

Comment: Sorry, missed a close parenthesis, try it now.

Comment: Yup works now, I'm using it as `city_count = City.objects.annotate(user_count=Count("user").filter(user_count__gt=1).count()`